# Crear explicitamente la tercera tabla desde un ManyToMany en Django

Tags: python, django

les explico: Tengo un pequeño proyecto en Django. Ya cree los modelos y voy avanzando, pero en una relación ManyToMany Django me creó una tercera tabla a la cual necesito agregar un campo mas. Esta tabla no esta en mi proyecto, si en la bd.
Tengo la tabla Producto y otra Venta (Django creó producto_venta), intenté crear el tercer modelo con el proyecto ya avanzado y no me resulta. la tabla intermedia la llamé Detalle_Venta. Pero al lanzar el comando migrate me lanza este error: 
"you cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M fields"

```
    # Modelo Producto
    class Producto(models.Model) :
    descripcion = models.TextField()
    precio = models.IntegerField()
    tipoProducto = models.ForeignKey(tipoProducto, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.descripcion)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.tipoProducto)

    # Modelo Venta
    class Venta(models.Model):
    id_venta = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    vendedor = models.ForeignKey(Vendedor, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    productos = models.ManyToManyField(Producto, blank=True, through='Detalle_Venta')
    total_venta = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.vendedor)


    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.productos)

   # Nuevo Modelo que quiero agregar
    class Detalle_Venta(models.Model) :
    id_producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_venta = models.ForeignKey(Venta, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cant_producto = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.id_venta)


    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.id_producto)


 # ERROR
 ValueError: Cannot alter field gestionVenta.Venta.productos into gestionVenta.Venta.productos - they are not compatible types (you cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M fields)
```

Comment: Aparentemente cualquier solución que no implique pérdida de datos implica unos buenos trucos de codigo. Tal vez pensaría alguna forma de guardar los datos actuales en alguna estructura intermedia como un json o csv y luego cargarlos sobre la base de datos limpia recién migrada.

Comment: de acuerdo a mi experiencia, quita la relación productos que esta en el modelo venta y trabajarlo tal cual, como quieres agregar este tercer modelo de detalle.